# Spray - IllegalURI exception

Tags: java, scala, http, spray

I am connecting to an API via Get call using spray client. 
Following is code for that :

```
  val response = HttpDialog(URI)
    .send(Get(String.format("message=%s",message)))
    .end
```

My message above is " Hi%20!@#$%,:().?~` "

But while connecting , I get IllegalUriException. Even tried using **uri-parsing-mode = relaxed-with-raw-query** in conf file.

Following is the stacktrace:

```
spray.http.IllegalUriException: Illegal URI reference, unexpected character    
',' at position 128: 
URI?message=Hi%20!@#$%,:().?~`                                                                                                                               
at spray.http.Uri$.fail(Uri.scala:775) ~[spray-http_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
at spray.http.parser.UriParser.complete(UriParser.scala:429) ~[spray-  
http_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
at spray.http.parser.UriParser.parseReference(UriParser.scala:60) ~[spray-
http_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
at spray.http.Uri$.apply(Uri.scala:231) ~[spray-http_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
at spray.http.Uri$.apply(Uri.scala:203) ~[spray-http_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
at   
spray.httpx.RequestBuilding$RequestBuilder.apply(RequestBuilding.scala:36) ~
[spray-httpx_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
at 
spray.httpx.RequestBuilding$RequestBuilder.apply(RequestBuilding.scala:34) ~
[spray-httpx_2.11-1.3.2.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use forbidden symbols in [query and fragment positions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4). Transformation to urlencoded string ( `Hi%2520!%40%23%24%25%2C%3A().%3F%7E%60` ) helps.

Comment: Note that you can use the `Uri` constructors to perform the escaping for you rather than doing it "by hand".